# The base of the product topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $(E_i, \mathcal{T_i})$  a family of topological spaces and $E=\prod_{i \in I} E_i$.
The product topology is the smallest topology on $E$ such that all projection maps are continuous.
the base of this topology is given by :
$\mathcal B=\{ \prod_{i\in I} U_i : \text{ $U_i$ open in $E_i$  for all $i\in I$, and $U_i =E_i$ for all but finitely many $i\in I$}\}$.

---

The problem is why we define the base of the product topology like that and didn't define it as in the finite case  : $\mathcal B=\{ \prod_{i\in I} U_i : \text{ $U_i$ open in $E_i$  for all $i\in I$} \}$.
I know that $\mathcal B$ in  this case is the base of the box topology but I didn't understand yet.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

If you have a collection of set $\mathcal A=\{A_i\}_{i\in\mathcal I}$, the coarse topology that contains $\mathcal A$ is the topology of basis $$\mathcal B=\left\{\bigcap_{j\in J}A_j\mid |\mathcal J|<\infty ,A_j\in \mathcal A\right\}.$$

---

In your case, denote $\pi_k: \prod_{\ell\in \mathcal K}E_\ell\to E_k$ defined by $$\pi_k((x_\ell)_{\ell\in\mathcal K})=x_k.$$
In particular, $\pi_k$ is continuous if and only if $$\pi_{k}^{-1}(U)=E_1\times ...\times E_{k-1}\times U\times E_{k+1}\times ...$$ is open in $\prod_{\ell\in \mathcal K}E_\ell$ for all $U$ open in $E_k$. So, in you case, $\mathcal A$ is a collection of sets of the form $\prod_{\ell\in \mathcal K}V_\ell$, where $V_\ell$ are open in $E_\ell$ and $V_\ell=E_\ell$ for all $\ell\in \mathcal K$, but one. Then $\mathcal B$ is the collection of sets of the form $\prod_{\ell\in\mathcal K}V_\ell$ where $V_\ell$ are open, and $V_\ell=E_\ell$ for all $\ell$, but finitely many $\ell$'s.

Comment: Thank you so much @Surb, I understand it now ! :)

Comment: Only one more question please, can you please suggest a book where i can found the  proof of the first result that you have used ( the finite intersection of elements of a collection of sets is the basis ...) !

Comment: @H_K: It comes from almost from the definition of a [basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology)#Definition_and_basic_properties)

Answer (score 2):

If $\pi_i : E \to E_i$ is the projection onto the $i$-th coordinate, the smallest topology on $E$ that makes each of the functions in $\{\pi_i\}_{i \in I}$ continuous [is](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_topology) the topology generated by $$\{\pi_i^{-1}(U_i) : i \in I,\, U_i \in \mathcal T_i\}.$$ Thus, a basis element for this topology is a finite intersection of the form $\pi_{i_1}^{-1}(U_1) \cap \cdots \cap \pi_{i_k}^{-1}(U_k)$, but note that $$\pi_{i_1}^{-1}(U_1) \cap \cdots \cap \pi_{i_k}^{-1}(U_k) = \{(x_i)_{i \in I} \in E : (\forall j \in \{1,\dots,k\}) \ x_{i_j} \in U_j\} = \prod_{i \in I} V_i$$ where $V_{i_j} = U_j$ for every $j \in \{1,\dots,k\}$, and $V_i = E_i$ if $i \neq i_1,\dots,i_k$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! but i didn't understand why a basis element should be a $\textbf{ finite }$ intesection ?

Comment: @H_K Recall that if $X$ is a *set*, and $S$ is a collection of subsets of $X$ whose union is $X$, then the  set of all finite intersections of members in $S$ is a basis for some topology on $X$, and this topology is called the topology *generated by $S$*.

Comment: I appreciate your help @azif00, I understand it now ! :)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is very simple: the product topology behaves much better than the box topology and is more useful. In particular, it has the following characteristics. Let $X=\prod_{i\in I}X_i$.

- For any space $Y$ and any function $f:Y\to X$, $f$ is continuous if and only if $\pi_i\circ f:Y\to X_i$ is continuous for each $i\in I$, where $\pi_i:X\to X_i$ is the projection map. The product topology is the **only** topology on $X$ with this property.
- $X$ is compact if and only if each of the spaces $X_i$ is compact. The box product makes the projection maps continuous, so half of this is still true for the box product: if $X$ is compact in the box topology, then each $X_i$ is compact. The other half, however, is the Tikhonov product theorem, which does not hold in general for the box topology. For instance, let $X_n$ be the discrete two-point space for each $n\in\Bbb N$; then the box topology on $\prod_{n\in\Bbb N}X_n$ is discrete, hence certainly not compact, while the product topology gives us a compact space homeomorphic to the middle-thirds Cantor set.
- $X$ is connected if and only if each $X_i$ is connected. Here again half of the theorem is true for the box topology: if $X$ is connected in the box topology, so is each of the spaces $X_i$. The other direction, however, can fail: if $X_n=\Bbb R$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$, $\prod_{n\in\Bbb N}X_n$ is not connected.

These properties alone are enough to justify taking the usual product topology as the standard one, but it is nicer than the box topology in other ways, especially when $I$ is countably infinite. If $I$ is countably infinite and each $X_i$ has one of the following properties, then $X$ with the product topology also has that property: separability, metrizability, first countability, second countability. None of these is preserved by the box topology when infinitely many of the $X_i$ are non-trivial.

Note that while it’s perfectly true that the first of the properties that I listed means that the usual product topology makes the topological product a category-theoretic product, it was established as the standard product topology before category theory came along.

Comment: Thank you so much @Brian_M._Scott :)

Comment: @H_K: You’re very welcome.

Answer (score 1):

It is the coarsest topology that makes all the projection morphisms continuous. This makes it align with the category theoretical definition of "product" (the "identity map" from the box topology space to the product topology space is continuous, but not the other way around), which is a good thing.

Also note that it *is*, formally, defined the same way for finite products. It's just that in those cases you don't see the distinction between box and product topologies. So for simplicity people usually quote the definition of box topology when they actually mean to talk about the product topology on finite products.

Comment: Thank you for helping me to inderstand :) @Arthur